# Create an instance for appened string

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to create a generic method where I have to append some string to Generic data type and create instance of that appended string.

Eg: 
I have two classes
  Object1,
  Object2,
  Object3,
  Object4,....Object100 and 
  Object1Address,
  Object2Address,
  Object3Address,
  Object4Address,....Object100Address

Right now I have method for each Object like MethodObject1(), MethodObject2(),MethodObject3(), MethodObject4()

```
MethodObject1()
{
     Object1 object = new Object1();
     Object1Address objectAddress = new Object1Address();

     TestMethod();
}

MethodObject2()
{
     Object2 object = new Object2();
     Object2Address objectAddress = new Object2Address();

     TestMethod();
}

MethodObject3()
{
     Object3 object = new Object3();
     Object3Address objectAddress = new Object3Address();

     TestMethod();
}

MethodObject4()
{
     Object4 object = new Object4();
     Object4Address objectAddress = new Object4Address();

     TestMethod();
}
.
.
.
MethodObject100()
{
     Object100 object = new Object100();
     Object100Address objectAddress = new Object100Address();

     TestMethod();
}
```

But there are around 100 object so I have to create 100 methods in similar way.
So I thought of creating an generic method.

```
There is a method which returns only the an array of Object name from an XML file.
Eg: ObjectName[] objectName = GetObjects(); // Returns an array of Object Names from XML file so that 

objectName[0] = Object1;
objectName[1] = Object2;
objectName[2] = Object3;
objectNmae[3] = Object4;
.
.
.
objectName[99] = Object100;

I am looping through objectName array
foreach(var objectItem in objectName)
{
    MethodName<objectItem>();
}

In my generic method I can create an instance of object, like
MethodName<T>()
{
   T t = new T();
   Some how I have to get the name of T and append Address to T 
   So that I can create TAddress instance like
   TAddress tAddress = new TAddress();

}
```

Is there any way I can do this using C sharp?

Comment: Why do you need a generic method if you are using `Person`? If you do need it to be generic, what similarities are between the different classes you are going to pass to it?

Comment: What Oded said. You are using everything that has to do with `Person` in a generic method. That's not the way to go.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have two arbitrary types `T` and `TAddress`, and `T` should have a method that takes a string creates a `TAddress`? Please clarify your question regarding this point.

Comment: The terminology in the question is confusing: 'append to' doesn't make sense in the manner it appears you're using it.  Could you be more specific on what you want to have as input and output?  It's unclear if you want an object instance that has Person and Address fields, or the ability to add a property 'string Address' onto an existing instance, or what.

Comment: With the latest edit it says "to append some string to Generic data type and create instance of that appended string" - so you want the signature to look like "string Method<T>(T item, string someString)"?  IOW, you want some item and a string as input, and then a string as output?

Answer (score 0):

Your case doesn't really require a generic method.

What you probably want is to override `ToString` method in your classes.

```
class PersonAddress()
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(this.Street, ", ",  this.City, ", ", this.Postcode);
    }
}

class Person()
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat(this.Name, ", ",  this.PersonAddress.ToString());
    }
}
```

Notice how `Person` class reuses `PersonAddress.ToString()` method.

Comment: Did you mean String.Concat?  String.Join is for collections

Comment: Yes, sorry. - Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the edits, I still can't follow what you're asking for.  However, in an attempt to make forward progress, I'll offer an answer that might at least help isolate what you want.

```
public class ThingWithAddress<T>
{
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }

    public static ThingWithAddress<T> Create(T item, string address)
    {
        return new ThingWithAddress<T>
        {
            Item = item,
            Address = address,
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can get an object that has both a person and address like:

```
Person person = ...;
var personWithAddress = ThingWithAddress.Create(person, "some address");
```

Don't take this the wrong way, but you might need to learn enough C# to formulate a good question, since as it stands, the question seems confusing and inconsistent.